# hbase search between composite keys - java

Tags: java, filter, hbase

In h base my row key is of the form  string+date e.g  :  abc+01/03/2012

Searching is based on 3 parameters (String,date,date) :

1.) First parameter string should match with row key before + sign, for that i have got

```
Filter rowFilter=new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryPrefixComparator(Bytes.toBytes(ticker)));
```

because this is searching prefix, if I search for "ab", I will get results for "ab" and "abc", what could be the condition for getting exact match?

2.) Second parameter date should be > then row key date extracted from row key abc+01/03/2012.

3.) Third parameter date should be < then row key date extracted from row key abc+01/03/2012.

basically dates should fall between provided dates only.

What is the possible solution for this? thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scan with setting start row and stop row,
so, you set start row= string+timestamp_1, stop row = string+timestamp_2.

If you need to find row like 'string*'+ts, then you need to write your own DatePostfixComparator(startTs, endTs).

The second case will be slower than first.

Comment: Thanks for reply working for dates.. i still have to figure out something replacement for prefix.

Comment: can I use RegexStringComparator comp = new RegexStringComparator("abc+"); on row instead of column.

Comment: RegexStringComparator can be used on row, qualifier and value